# jquery mobile trigger create method

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was wondering how I'd call `.trigger("create")` method after injecting a table dynamically.

I found this in jquery mobile docs

```
$("...new markup that contains widgets...")
               .appendTo(".ui-page")
               .trigger( "create" );
```

But, (due to my limited knowledge) I do not know what I must replace *new markup that contains widgets...* with - is it the ID of the table I'm using?

Here's what I've tried till now :

**JS**

```
$(".ui-responsive").trigger("create");
```

**How the HTML is injected**

```
{
   title:'test-jqry', 
   content:'<table data-role="table" id="testjqtable" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke jqm-table"><thead><tr><th data-priority="1">Rank</th><th data-priority="persist">Movie Title</th><th data-priority="2">Year</th><th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th><th data-priority="4">Reviews</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th>1</th><td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td><td>1941</td><td>100%</td><td>74</td></tr><tr><th>2</th><td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td><td>1942</td><td>97%</td><td>64</td></tr><tr><th>3</th><td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">The Godfather</a></td><td>1972</td><td>97%</td><td>87</td></tr><tr><th>4</th><td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">Gone with the Wind</a></td><td>1939</td><td>96%</td><td>87</td></tr><tr><th>5</th><td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">Lawrence of Arabia</a></td><td>1962</td><td>94%</td><td>87</td></tr></tbody></table>'
}
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle for this @ http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: You can use any selector `$('#id')` or `$('.class')` or `$('[data-role=role]')`...etc

Comment: I tryied that It seems only the content inside the table get effected but none of the jqm css works for the table its not responsive .

Comment: ui-table ui-table-reflow these classes are missing they are added in the run time i guess but I do not know why they are not there

Comment: are you trying to create a table dynamically? `$('[data-role=table]').trigger('create');` should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a demo : http://jsbin.com/umatel/1/edit

According to jQuery Mobile's [docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/faq/triggering-create-on-injected-content-does-not-work.php), you cant call `trigger` on individual elements. Call it on the parent of the element. In your case that would be `div[data-role=page]`. So after you *inject* your HTML into the page, call trigger like this  :

```
 //first is the div with data-role set to page. for more info, see demo
 $("#first").trigger("create");
```

Hope this clears things up.