# RangeSliders disappears after .submit()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-mobile

I have a dropdown and a rangeslider using jQuery mobile for a Rails form:

```
<%= form_tag(profile_path, remote: true, id: 'search_forms') do %>
  <%= select_tag 'q[activity]', options_from_collection_for_select(activities, :slug, :title, q[:activity]), id: 'activ_sel', prompt: "Select an activity" %>

  <div id="time-slider" data-role="rangeslider">            
    <input name="range1a" id="range1a" min="4" max="21" value="<%= @h1 %>" type="range" />
    <input name="range1b" id="range1b" min="4" max="21" value="<%= @h2 %>" type="range" />
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#activ_sel").change(function(){
      $('#search_forms').submit();
     });
  </script>

<% end %>
```

My current setup is to submit after the dropdown changes and afterwards I'd also like to implement this for the slider.

While the submit works well the problem is that after submitting the slider breaks which looks like this:  [image]

I have the jQuery Mobile library on my javascripts assets and loading it through the `//= require_tree .` line in the application.js file.

Comment: add `data-ajax=false` to search form.

Comment: No, that didn't work. I was thinking it could be that the jQuery Mobile library is not initialising the widget because it doesn't get reloaded. This is what happens when I call enable on it after a .submit(): `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on rangeslider prior to initialization;` Also I'm not loading Turbolinks from application.js

Comment: I dont know how ruby works, but what happens when you submit? does the active page refresh? do you replace elements with new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation on why this was not working is that on calling `.submit()` and having form set to `remote: true` the request was sent but didn't trigger a library reload for jQuery Mobile as expected of an AJAX call.

> Note: Remember to attach the mobileinit handler after you have loaded jQuery, but before you load jQuery Mobile, because the event is triggered as part of jQuery Mobile's loading process.

I'm thinking that submitting unbounded (not sure why) the `div` used for the Range Slider and didn't bind again because it didn't reload the library.

In any case what solved this was calling a `.trigger("create")` on the parent element to re attach the widget.

About `.trigger()`:

> Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Thanks for the help @Omar, also please consider closing this question as duplicate of: [jquery mobile trigger create method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997854/jquery-mobile-trigger-create-method)

Ref: http://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/

Comment: Call `.enhanceWithin()` on parent div. trigger create is deprecated and will be removed.